# How does finding a cycle start node in a cycle linked list work?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, cycle, floyd-cycle-finding

I understand that Tortoise and Hare's meeting concludes the existence of a loop, but how does moving tortoise to the beginning of linked list while keeping the hare at the meeting place, followed by moving both one step at a time make them meet at the starting point of the cycle?

Comment: Another explanation: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/find-cycle-start-in-singly-linked-list

Comment: I wonder if anyone can find the start of the cycle easily if Brent's algorithm is used.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This is [Floyd's algorithm for cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare).  You are asking about the second phase of the algorithm -- once you've found a node that's part of a cycle, how does one find the *start* of the cycle?

In the first part of Floyd's algorithm, the hare moves two steps for every step of the tortoise.  If the tortoise and hare ever meet, there is a cycle, and the meeting point is part of the cycle, but not necessarily the first node in the cycle.

When the tortoise and hare meet, we have found the smallest i (the number of steps taken by the tortoise) such that X<sub>i</sub> = X<sub>2i</sub>. Let mu represent the number of steps to get from X<sub>0</sub> to the start of the cycle, and let lambda represent the length of the cycle.  Then i = mu + a*lambda, and 2i = mu + b*lambda, where a and b are integers denoting how many times the tortoise and hare went around the cycle. Subtracting
the first equation from the second gives i = (b-a)*lambda, so i is an integer multiple
of lambda.  **Therefore, X<sub>i + mu</sub> = X<sub>mu</sub>**.  X<sub>i</sub> represents the meeting point of the tortoise and hare.  If you move the tortoise back to the starting node X<sub>0</sub>, and let the tortoise and hare continue at the same speed, after mu additional steps the tortoise will have reached X<sub>mu</sub>, and the hare will have reached X<sub>i + mu</sub> = X<sub>mu</sub>, so the second meeting point denotes the start of the cycle.

Comment: @Jim lewis The meeting point will not be a starting point of course, but as I said shifting one of those two to beginning of linked list and moving both at same speed will make them meet at the starting point of cycle.

Comment: @Passionate: Hope this edit clarifies the situation.  The key insight is that the number of (tortoise) steps to the first meeting must be a multiple of the cycle length, and that mu steps from either this position or the start position will take you to the start of the cycle.

Comment: @Jim Lewis It would be great if you could explain about how having i as multiple of loop length results to mu as distance between first meeting point and loop beginning.

Comment: @Passionate: Take mu steps from the start point to get to `X_mu`, the start of the cycle (by definition of mu).  Then if you take i more steps, where i is a multiple of the cycle length, you end up back at the cycle start: `X_mu + i` = `X_mu`. But addition is commutative, so this is equivalent to taking i steps to get from the start to the first meeting point `X_i`, then mu additional steps to get back to `X_mu`, the start of the cycle.

Comment: @JimLewis : i understood the part that i always has to be multiple of cycle length but the step "X_mu + i = X_mu" in which you are adding the value of mu to the i is not clear to me. Well why you added the value of mu to the i ? Can't it be any other value ? That part is not clear to me. It would really a great help if you can elaborate it.

Comment: @ankur: Perhaps it would have been clearer if I had written "X_(mu + i) = X_mu" (with (mu + i) being the subscript).  If you start at node X_mu (by definition, the first node of the cycle), then take i steps, you will end up at node X_mu again, since i is an exact multiple of the cycle length.  Does that help?

Comment: @JimLewis : Sorry but i am still not smart enough to understand it. Still my mind is not able to understand why the distance is mu from the meeting point to loop start point. why it is not any other distance?

Comment: @ankur:  The meeting point is X_i, and we have shown (third paragraph in my answer) that i must be a multiple of the loop length.  After mu additional steps past the meeting point, you are now at X_(i + mu).  But we have shown that X_(i + mu) = X_(mu + i) = X_mu, because of this special property of i, so mu steps past the meeting point must take you to X_mu, the start of the cycle. Basically modular arithmetic, plus the commutative property of addition.

Comment: I think there is a small problem in your proof. Since the meeting point `i` is at some point of the cycle, I think the equation should be `i = mu + k + a*lambda` and `2i = mu + k + b*lambda`, where `k` is the number of step from cycle start to the meeting point. Subtracting both equations give the same result though.

Answer (score 390):

Let me try to clarify the cycle detection algorithm that is provided at [Wikipedia - Tortoise_and_hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) in my own words.

[image: drawing]

**How it works**

Let's have a tortoise and a hare (name of the pointers) pointing to the beginning of the list with a cycle, as in the diagram above.

Let's hypothesize that if we move the tortoise 1 step at a time, and the hare 2 steps at a time, they will eventually meet at a point. Let's show that first of all this hypothesis is true.

The figure illustrates a list with a cycle. The cycle has a length of `n` and we are initially `m` steps away from the cycle. Also, let's say that the meeting point is `k` steps away from the cycle beginning and tortoise and hare meets when tortoise has taken `i` total steps.  (Hare would have taken `2i` total steps by then.).

The following 2 conditions must hold:

```
1) i = m + p * n + k

2) 2i = m + q * n + k
```

The first one says that the tortoise moves `i` steps and in these `i` steps, it first gets to the cycle. Then it goes through the cycle `p` times for some positive number `p`. Finally, it goes over `k` more nodes until it meets hare.

A similar thing is true for hare. It moves `2i` steps and in these `2i` steps it first gets to the cycle. Then it goes through the cycle `q` times for some positive number `q`. Finally, it goes over `k` more nodes until it meets the tortoise.

As the hare travels with double the speed of the tortoise, and time is constant for both when they reach the meeting point.

So by using simple speed, time and distance relation,

```
2 ( m + p * n + k ) = m + q * n + k

=> 2m + 2pn + 2k = m + nq + k 

=>  m + k = ( q - 2p ) n
```

Among `m`, `n`, `k`, `p`, `q`, the first two are properties of the given list. If we can show that there is at least one set of values for `k`, `q`, `p` that makes this equation true we show that the hypothesis is correct.

One such solution set is as follows:

```
p = 0

q = m

k = m n - m
```

We can verify that these values work as follows:

```
m + k = ( q - 2p ) n  

=> m + mn - m = ( m - 2*0) n

=> mn = mn
```

For this set, `i` is

```
i = m + p n + k

=> m + 0 * n + mn - m = mn
```

Of course, you should see that this is not necessarily the smallest `i` possible. In other words, tortoise and hare might have already met before many times. However, since we show that they meet at some point at least once we can say that the hypothesis is correct. So they would have to meet if we move one of them by 1 step, and the other one by 2 steps at a time.

Now we can go to the second part of the algorithm which is how to find the beginning of the cycle.

**Cycle Beginning**

Once tortoise and hare meet, let's put tortoise back to the beginning of the list and keep hare where they met (which is `k` steps away from the cycle beginning).

The hypothesis is that if we let them move at the same speed (1 step for both), the first time they ever meet again will be the cycle beginning.

Let's prove this hypothesis.

Let's first assume some oracle tells us what `m` is.

Then, if we let them move `m + k` steps, the tortoise would have to arrive at the point they met originally (`k` steps away from the cycle beginning - see in the figure).

Previously we showed that `m + k = (q - 2p) n`.

Since `m + k` steps is a multiple of cycle length `n`, hare, in the meantime, would go through the cycle (`q-2p`) times and would come back to the same point (`k` steps away from the cycle beginning).

Now, instead of letting them move `m + k` steps, if we let them move only `m` steps, the tortoise would arrive at the cycle beginning. Hare would be `k` steps short of completing (`q-2p`) rotations. Since it started `k` steps in front of the cycle beginning, the hare would have to arrive at the cycle beginning.

As a result, this explains that they would have to meet at the cycle beginning after some number of steps for the very first time (very first time because the tortoise just arrived at the cycle after `m` steps and it could never see hare which was already in the cycle).

Now we know that the number of steps we need to move them until they meet turns out to be the distance from the beginning of the list to the cycle beginning, `m`. Of course, the algorithm does not need to know what `m` is. It will just move both tortoise and hare one step at a time until they meet. The meeting point has to be the cycle start and the number of steps must be the distance (`m`) to the cycle beginning. Assuming we know the length of the list, we can also, compute the length of the cycle of subtracting `m` from the list length.

Comment: I don't think so its true that when they meet that's the starting point see comment below : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209858/1744146<br> Please let me know If I am wrong

Comment: First part of explanation is flawless. But Second part has a flaw as far as I know. You are assuming that "some oracle says m", but if m is known, you already have the beginning of the cycle. How can you just assume the answer when you never know where is the start of cycle?? Please let me know.

Comment: @Gopichand Read the last para again...you just assume that there is some m (if it is already proved that there is a cycle)..but you don't know the value of m

Comment: I wanted to ask even if the fast pointer is thrice as fast as the slow pointer or four times or n times as fast as the slow pointer, the slow and fast pointer would still meet, right?

Comment: @ankitG : Yes they will meet if we advance it thrice as fast. However they will now meet 2*offset away from the starting node. So to find the location of the start cycle, we will have to move the pointer in the cycle at speed 2x compared to the one in the beginning of the list. Why ? Because now the faster pointer has a 2*offset headstart in the list.

Comment: @rajaditya_m : I am not really concerned about finding the starting node of the cycle here. My question basically is that once both the tortoise and the hare are in the loop, will they necessarily meet irrespective of the speed of the hare? Why? Why not?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Assuming that we know a linked list is circular, I was wondering why we can't just use a Set to keep track of visited nodes in the linked list? [something like this](http://hastebin.com/ibiluqotez.coffee)

Comment: @Mido the `set` solution requires additional `O(n)` spaces while this one doesn't.

Comment: In the second part (cycle beginning), you said that `m + k = (q - 2p) n`. But that equation was derived when hare moved at twice the speed of tortoise. Now that they move at the same speed, does the equation still hold?

Comment: This is the best explanation in simple words. Could you please do the world a favor and edit the Wikipedia page for this algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection

Comment: Your Equation `m + k = (q - 2p) n` can be further simplified to `m + k = q*n`. This is because the number of loops tortoise takes will always be zero since the hare can never overtake the tortoise without meeting it. Think about it.

Comment: @CEGRD In the first part of explanation of how it works, could you please elaborate more on how you **derived** the solution set consisting of `p=0` and especially `q=m` to satisfy the final equation?

Answer (score 145):

Refer this image:

[image]

**Distance travelled by slowPointer before meeting** = x + y

**Distance travelled by fastPointer before meeting** = (x + y + z) + y
                                                                                = x + 2y + z

Since fastPointer travels with **double** the speed of slowPointer, and **time is constant** for both when the reach the meeting point.

So by using simple speed, time and distance relation
                     2(x+y)=  x+2y+z
               => x+2y+z = 2x+2y
               => x=z

Hence by moving **slowPointer** to start of linked list, and making both slowPointer and fastPointer to move one node at a time, **they both have same distance to cover** .

They will reach at the point where the loop starts in the linked list.

Comment: This does not take into account the case that fastPointer travels the cycle n times before slowPointer enters the cycle. Use l to denote the length of the cycle. __Distance travelled by fastPointer before meeting__ = (x + y + z) + y = x + 2y + nl + z. And the resulting relation will be x = nl+z.

Comment: @JingguoYao: Here is the explanation for [that case.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36214925/1835769)

Comment: this diagram is over-simple.  the fast pointer can move many times through the cycle before the slow pointer reaches it.

Comment: @Warren MacEvoy: It is a good thing that this diagram is simple. It helps to understand the base case. The next case is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36214925/1835769). That case is equally simple to understand.

Comment: @Warren MacEvoy "the fast pointer can move many times through the cycle before the slow pointer reaches it." Isn't the fast pointer that meets the slow pointer at the same place, and not the other way around? It could be perspective though.

Answer (score 82):

<sub>*[Old Monk's simple and under-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190575/1835769) explains finding the cycle when the fast runner completes only single  full cycle. In this answer I explain the case when fast runner has run the loop multiple times before the slow runner enters the loop.*</sub>

---

Using the same image:[image]

Let's say the fast runner has run the loop *m* times before slow and fast meet. This means that:

- Distance run by slow: *x + y*
- Distance run by fast: *x + m(y + z) + y* i.e. extra *y* where they meet

Since fast runs with twice the speed of slow, and that they have been running for same time, it implies that if we double the distance ran by slow, we get the distance ran by fast. Thus,

- *2(x + y) = x + m(y + z) + y*

Solving for x gives,

> *x = (m - 1)(y + z) + z*

In real scenario it would mean, *x* = *(m - 1)* complete loop runs + an extra distance *z*.

Hence, if we put one pointer at the start of the list and leave the other one at the meeting point, then moving them by the same speed will result in the in loop pointer completing *m - 1* runs of the loop and then meeting the other pointer right at the loop beginning.

Comment: One doubt.. how  its guaranteed that slow and fast will meet before slow takes more than one cycle?

Comment: @siraj: Slow won't run in cycles, fast would as it is running faster than slow and will enter the loop before. And it's guaranteed that they would meet. If slow is at j + 1 and fast is at j, they will now meet at j + 2. And if slow is at j and fast at j + 1, it means that they already met at j - 1.

Comment: the math still works if slow goes around loop: x+(y+z)m+y = 2(x+(y+z)n+y), where n is # of times around loop for slow before they meet. This solves to (m-2n-1)(y+z)+z=x. Which means starting at meeting point, go around (m-2n-1) times, you are back at meeting point, an then go z, you are at start of loop. And to do this it is the same as starting at the head node and going x nodes.

Comment: @mayas_mom: Math may be working out but slow will never be able to go around the loop. It will always be caught either right at the start or somewhere mid-way.

Comment: @displayName - In "Hence, if we put one pointer at the start of the loop"... shouldn't it be "at the start of the list"? It is throwing me off a bit.

Comment: @srinivas.naik: You are right. I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: x = (m - 1)(y + z) + z this can be  generalized as loop length is y+z and since are only concerned about position.
So x = ((m - 1)(y + z))%(y+z)) + z
Which is effectively x=z;

Comment: @WarrenMacEvoy: If you follow the exact steps of the answer, the slow and fast pointer will meet at **loop beginning**, not the starting point.

Comment: @displayName, You said in your comment to siraj: " If slow is at j + 1 and fast is at j, they will now meet at j + 2. And if slow is at j and fast at j + 1, it means that they already met at j - 1". Suppose when slow is at j, fast is at j-m and they will meet at j+k. What is the proof that k<n where n=total step length of the loop ?

Comment: @displayName, " There are only two cases possible - either fast lands over slow in every iteration or it lands over slow in every other iteration. (1/2)" - can you expliain a bit more ?

Comment: "Hence, if we put one pointer at the start of the list and leave the other one at the meeting point, then moving them by the same speed will result in the in loop pointer completing m - 1 runs of the loop and then meeting the other pointer right at the loop beginning." Terrible explanation. The two nodes start at the beginning.

Comment: @AleksandrH: They start at the head node but after they have met each other inside the loop, then you have to bring one of them to head again and leave other one at the meeting point. And then move both of them one node at a time. That is how they will meet again at the loop beginning. (Feel free to edit and update the answer if you can make it better.)

Comment: @Tommy: Yeah.. I tried to understand the solution to this problem from CTCI. But it was so tedious. I understood the [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190575/1835769) in one go. Then after seeing the missing case in the above solution, I ended up writing this addendum.

Answer (score 16):

It's very very simple. You can think in terms of relative speed. If the rabbit moves two nodes and tortoise moves one node, relative to tortoise rabbit is moving one node(assume tortoise at rest). So, if we move one node in the circular linked list we are sure going to meet at that point again.

After finding the connected point inside the circular linked list, now the problem is reduced to finding the intersection point of two linked list problem.

Comment: I tried very hard to appreciate this answer, but this statement makes no sense to me "_if we move one node in the circular linked list we are sure going to meet at that point again_"

Answer (score 12):

**Approach:**

There are two pointers:

- A slow pointer that moves one node at a time.
- A fast pointer that moves two nodes at a time.

If the two pointer meet, it proves that there is a loop. Once they have met, one of the nodes will point to the head and then have both proceed one node at a time. They will meet at the start of the loop.

**Rationale:**
When two people walk down a circular track, one of them at twice the speed of the other, where do they meet? Exactly where they started.

Now, suppose the fast runner has a head start of `k` steps in an `n` step lap. where will they meet? Exactly at `n-k` steps. When the slow runner has covered `(n-k)` steps, the fast runner would have covered `k+2(n-k)` steps.
(*ie, `k+2n-2k` steps ie `2n-k` steps*). i.e.`(n-k)` steps (The path is circular and we are not concerned about the number of rounds after which they meet; We are just interested in the position where they meet).

Now how did the fast runner get the head start of `k` steps in the first place? Because it took the slow runner that many steps to reach the start of the loop. So the start of the loop is k steps from the head node.

**Note:** The node where both pointer met is `k` steps away from start of loop (inside the loop) and the head node also is `k` steps away from start of loop. So when we have pointer advancing at equal pace of 1 step from bot these nodes, they will meet at the start of the loop.

I believe it is straightforward. Please let me know if any part is ambiguous.

Comment: Please post the full answer here instead of just a link which may break in the future

Answer (score 11):

[image: Figure 1]

At the time of the first collision, tortoise moved ***m+k*** steps as show above. Hare moves twice as fast as tortoise, meaning hare moved ***2(m+k)*** steps. From these simple facts we can derive the following graph.

[image: Figure 1]

At this point, we move tortoise back to the start and declare that both hare and tortoise must move one step at a time. By definition, after ***m*** steps, tortoise will be at the start of the cycle. Where will hare be?

Hare will also be at the start of the cycle. This is clear from the second graph: When tortoise was moved back to the start, hare was ***k*** steps into its last cycle. After ***m*** steps, hare will have completed another cycle and collided with tortoise.

Comment: @WarrenMacEvoy At no point did I suggest that they meet at the starting point. They meet again at the *start of the cycle* as the figures clearly point out.

Answer (score 5):

Okay so lets assume the hare and the tortoise meet at a point which is k steps away from the starting of the cycle, the number of steps before the cycle starts is mu and the length of the cycle is L.

So now at the meeting point ->

Distance covered by tortoise = mu + a*L + k    - Equation 1

(Steps taken to reach the beginning of the cycle + steps taken to cover 'a' iterations of the cycle + k steps from the start of the cycle)
(where a is some positive constant)

Distance covered by the hare = mu + b*L + k     - Equation 2

(Steps taken to reach the beginning of the cycle + steps taken to cover 'b' iterations of the cycle + k steps from the start of the cycle)
(where b is some positive constant and b>=a)

So the extra distance covered by the hare is = Equation 2 - Equation 1 = (b-a)*L

Please note that this distance is also equal to the distance of the tortoise from the starting point since the hare moves 2 times faster than the tortoise. This can be equated to 'mu+k' which is also the distance of the meeting point from the beginning if we do not include multiple traversals of the cycle.

Thus,
  mu + k = (b-a)*L

So mu steps from this point would lead back to the beginning of the cycle (since k steps from the start of the cycle have already been taken to reach the meeting point). This could happen in the same cycle or any of the subsequent cycles.
Thus now if we move the tortoise to beginning of the linked list, it will take mu steps to reach the starting point of the cycle and the hare would take mu steps to also reach the beginning of the cycle and thus they would both meet at the starting point of the cycle.

P.S. Honestly, I had the same question as the original poster in my mind and I read the first answer, they did clear out a few things but I could not get to the final result clearly and so I tried to do it my own way and found it easier to understand.

Comment: they usually do not meet at the beginning of the cycle

Answer (score 5):

A simple explanation using the idea of [relative velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity) taught in high school - Physics 101 / Kinematics lectures.

[image: Circle in LinkedList]

1. Let's assume distance from start of linked list to start of the circle is `x` hops. Let's call the start of circle as point `X` (in caps - see figure above). Also let's assume total size of circle is N hops.
2. Speed of hare = 2 * Speed of tortoise. So that is `1 hops/sec` and `2 hops/sec` respectively
3. When tortoise reaches the start of the circle `X`, the hare must further be `x` hops away at point `Y` in the figure. (Because hare has travelled twice the distance as the tortoise).
4. Thus, length of the remaining arc clockwise from X to Y would be `N-x`. T**his also happens to be the relative distance to be covered between the hare and the tortoise for them to be able to meet**. Let's say this relative distance will be covered in time `t_m` i.e. time to meet. Relative speed is `(2 hops/sec - 1 hops/sec)` i.e. `1 hops/sec`. Thus using, relative distance = relative speed X time, we get, `t` = `N-x` sec. So it will take `N-x` to reach the meeting point for both the tortoise and the hare.
5. Now in `N-x` sec time and at `1 hops/sec` speed, the tortoise who was earlier at point `X` will cover N-x hops to reach the meeting point `M`. So, that means the meeting point `M` is at `N-x` hops counterclockwise from `X` = (which further implies) => that there is `x` distance remaining from point `M` to `X` clockwise.
6. But `x` is also the distance to reach point `X` from the start of the linked list.
7. Now, we don't care what number of hops `x` corresponds to. If we put one tortoise at the start of the LinkedList and one tortoise at the meeting point `M` and let them hop/walk, then they will meet at point `X`, which is the point (or node) that we need.

Answer (score 4):

**Reduce the problem to a loop problem, then go back to the initial problem**

I find the following explanation more intuitive.

1. Take two pointers (**1** = tortoise and **2** = hare) that start from the head (**O**), **1** has a step length of **1**, **2** has a step length of **2**. Think about the moment when **1** reaches the start node of that cycle (**A**).

   We want to answer to the following question **"Where is 2 when 1 is in A?"**.

   So, `OA = a` is a natural number (`a >= 0`). But it can be written in the following way: `a = k*n + b`, where `a, k, n, b are natural numbers`:

   - `n` = the cycle length
   - `k >= 0` = constant
   - `0 <= b <= n-1`

   It means that `b = a % n`.

   E.g.: if `a = 20` and `n = 8` => `k = 2` and `b = 4` because `20 = 2*8 + 4`.

   The distance covered by **1** is `d = OA = a = k*n + b`. But in the same time, **2** covers `D = 2*d = d + d = OA + d = OA + k*n + b`. This means that when **2** is in A it has to cover `k*n + b`. As you can see, `k` is the number of laps, but after those laps, **2** will be **b** far from A. So, we found where **2** is when **1** is in A. Let's call that point `B`, where `AB = b`.

   [image]
2. Now, we reduce the problem to a circle. The question is **"Where is the meeting point?"**. Where is that **C**?

   [image]

   In every step, **2** reduces the distance from **1** with `1` (let's say meter) because **1** is getting further from **2** with `1`, but at the same time **2** goes closer to **1** by `2`.

   So, the intersection will be when the distance between **1** and **2** will be zero. This means that **2** reduces the `n - b` distance. In order to achieve this, **1** will make `n - b` steps, while **2** will make `2*(n - b)` steps.

   So, the intersection point will be `n - b` far from **A** (clockwise), because this is the distance covered by **1** until it meets **2**. => the distance between **C** and **A** is `CA = b`, because `AC = AB + BC = n - b` and `CA = n - AC`. Don't think that `AC = CA`, because the `AC` distance is not a trivial mathematical distance, it is the number of steps between **A** and **C** (where **A** is the start point and **C** is the end point).
3. Now, let's go back to the initial schema.

   We know that `a = k*n + b` and `CA = b`.

   We can take 2 new pointers **1'** and **1''**, where **1'** starts from the head (**O**) and **1''** starts from the intersection point (**C**).

   While **1'** goes from **O** to **A**, **1''** goes from **C** to **A** and continues to finish `k` laps. So, the intersection point is **A**.

   [image]

   [image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

If the pointers met at a point P as shown in the figure, the distance Z+Y is point P and X+Y is also point P which means Z=X. Which is why keeping moving one pointer from P and moving another from start(S) till they meet, which means moving an equal distance(Z or X) to the same point M(distance Z from P and X from S) will be the starting of the loop. Simple!

Answer (score 4):

There are already plenty of answers to this, but I once came up with a diagram for this which is more visually intuitive to me. Perhaps it can help other people.

The main aha-moments for me were:

- Split *T* (tortoise) into *T1* (pre-loop) and *T2* (in-loop).
  [image: T = tortoise, H = hare]
- Subtract *T* from *H*, where they visually overlap. What remains (*H - T = H'*) is equal to *T*.
- The remaining math is quite simple.
  [image: From H, subtract where T visually overlaps]

Answer (score 3):

-there are k steps before the loop.  We don't know what k is and don't need to find out.  We can work abstractly with just k.

--After k steps

----- T is at cycle beginning

----- H is k steps into cycle  (he went 2k total and thus k into loop)

**  they are now loopsize - k apart

(note that k == K == mod(loopsize, k)  --e.g. if a node is 2 steps into a 5 node cycle it is also 7, 12 or 392 steps in, so how big the cycle is w.r.t k does not factor in.

Since they catch up to each other at the rate of 1 step per unit of time because one is moving twice as fast as the other, they will meet at loopsize - k.

This means it will take k nodes to reach the beginning of the cycle and thus the distance from head to cyclestart and collision to cyclestart are the same.

So now after first collision move T back to head. T and H will meet at cyclestart if you move at rate of 1 each.  (in k steps for both)

This means that the algorithm is:

- from head move T = t.next and H.next.next until they collide ( T == H) (there is a cycle)

//take care of case when k=0 or T and H met at the head of the loop by 
calculating the length of the loop

--count the length of the cycle by moving T or H around it with a counter

--move a pointer T2 to head of list

--move pointer length of cycle steps

--move another pointer H2 to head

--move T2 and H2 in tandem until they meet at start of cycle

that's it!

Answer (score 3):

[image] [image credit](https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/find-cycle-start-in-singly-linked-list)

Call distance the number of links a pointer follows, and time the number of iterations the algorithm takes of moving the slow pointer one link and the fast pointer two links. There are N nodes before a cycle of length C, labeled with cycle offset k=0 through C-1.

To reach the start of the cycle, slow takes N time and distance. This means fast takes N distance in the cycle (N to get there, N to spin).  So at time N, slow is at cycle offset k=0, and fast is at cycle offset k=N mod C.

If N mod C is zero, slow and fast now match and the cycle is found at time N and cycle position k=0.

If N mod C is not zero, then fast now has to catch up with slow, which at time N is C-(N mod C) distance behind in the cycle.

Since fast moves 2 for every 1 of slow, reducing the distance by 1 on every iteration, this takes as much additional time as the distance between fast and slow at time N, which is C-(N mod C).  Since slow is moving from offset 0, this is also the offset where they meet.

So, if N mod C is zero, the phase 1 stops after N iterations at the beginning of the cycle.  Otherwise, phase 1 stops after N+C-(N mod C) iterations at offset C-(N mod C) into the cycle.

```
// C++ pseudocode, end() is one after last element.

int t = 0;
T *fast = begin();
T *slow = begin();
if (fast == end()) return [N=0,C=0];
for (;;) {
    t += 1;
    fast = next(fast);
    if (fast == end()) return [N=(2*t-1),C=0];
    fast = next(fast);
    if (fast == end()) return [N=(2*t),C=0];
    slow = next(slow);
    if (*fast == *slow) break;
}
```

Ok, so phase 2: slow takes N more steps to get to the cycle, at which point fast (now moving 1 per time step) is at (C-(N mod C)+N) mod C = 0.  So they meet at the beginning of the cycle after phase 2.

```
int N = 0;
slow = begin();
for (;;) {
    if (*fast == *slow) break;
    fast = next(fast);
    slow = next(slow);
    N += 1;
}
```

For completeness, phase 3 computes the cycle length by moving once more through the cycle:

```
int C = 0;
for (;;) {
    fast = next(fast);
    C += 1;
    if (fast == slow) break;
}
```

Comment: Link to google doc to simulate algorithm: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXEBc3EqrkQkUycx5oA_yqEZRbjBMIvrW5rt9oxb-IY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Note that, if N <= C, the iteration stops after C iterations. In any case it must stop in less than N+C steps and is unlikely to stop at the beginning of the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

With all the above analysis, if you are a learn-by-example person, I tried to write up an short analysis and example that help explains the math everyone else attempted to explain. Here we go!

**Analysis:**

If we have two pointers, one faster than the other, and move them along together, they will eventually meet again to indicate a cycle or null to indicate no cycle.

To find the starting point of the cycle, let ...

1. `m` be the distance from head to the beginning of the cycle;
2. `d` be the number of nodes in the cycle;
3. `p1` be the speed of the slower pointer;
4. `p2` be the speed of the faster pointer, eg. 2 means steps through two nodes at a time.

   Observe the following iterations:

> ```
>  m = 0, d = 10:
>  p1 = 1:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 // 0 would the start of the cycle
>  p2 = 2:  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
>
>  m = 1, d = 10:
>  p1 = 1: -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
>  p2 = 2: -1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
>
>  m = 2, d = 10:
>  p1 = 1: -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
>  p2 = 2: -2  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
> ```

From the above sample data, we can easily discover that whenever the faster and the slower pointers  meet, they are `m` steps away from the start of the cycle. To solve this, put the faster pointer  back at the head and set its speed to the speed of the slower pointer. When they meet again, the node is the start of the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Working this with a diagram would help. I am trying to explain the problem without equations.

1. If we let the hare and tortoise run in a circle and hare runs two times tortoise then, at end of one lap for hare tortoise would be at half. At end of two laps from hare tortoise would have done 1 lap and they both meet. This applies to all speed like if hare runs three times, hare 1 lap is equal to 1/3 of tortoise so at end of 3 laps for hare tortoise would have covered 1 lap and they meet.
2. Now if we start them m steps before loop, then it means the faster hare is starting ahead in loop. So if tortoise reach the start of loop the hare is m steps ahead loop and when they meet it would be m steps before the loop start.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so its true that when they meet that's the starting point. But yes if the other pointer(F) was at the meeting point before , than that pointer will be at the end of the loop instead of the start of the loop and the pointer(S) which started from the start of the list it will end up at the start of the loop. for eg:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10->11->12->13->14->15->16->17->18->19->20->21->22->23->24->8

Meet at :16

Start at :8

public Node meetNodeInLoop(){

    Node fast=head;
    Node slow=head;

    fast=fast.next.next;
    slow=slow.next;

    while(fast!=slow){

        fast=fast.next;
        fast=fast.next;

        if(fast==slow) break; 

        slow=slow.next;
    }

    return fast;

}

public Node startOfLoop(Node meet){

    Node slow=head;
    Node fast=meet;

    while(slow!=fast){
        fast=fast.next;
        if(slow==fast.next) break;
        slow=slow.next;
    }

    return slow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

lets say,

```
N[0] is the node of start of the loop, 
m is the number of steps from beginning to N[0].
```

we have 2 pointers A and B, A runs at 1x speed, B at 2x speed, both start at the beginning.

when A reaches N[0], B should be already in N[m]. 
(Note: A uses m steps to reach N[0], and B should be m steps further)

Then, A runs k more steps to collide to B, 
i.e. A is at N[k],  B is at N[m+2k]
(Note: B should runs for 2k steps starting from N[m])

A collide B at N[k] and N[m+2k] respectively, it means
k=m+2k, thus k = -m

Thus, to cycle back to the N[0] from N[k], we need m more steps.

Simply saying, we just need to run m more steps after we found the collision node. We can have a pointer to run from beginning and a pointer running from collision node, they will meet at N[0] after m steps.

Therefore, the pseudo code are as follow:

```
1) A increase 1 step per loop
2) B increase 2 steps per loop
3) if A & B are the same node, cycle found, then go to 5
4) repeat from 1
5) A reset to head
6) A increase 1 step per loop
7) B increase 1 step per loop
8) if A & B are the same node, start of the cycle found
9) repeat from 6
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending two hours trying to read all the answers, I found this comment on leetcode. Safe to say, it saved my night.

https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle-ii/discuss/44774/Java-O(1)-space-solution-with-detailed-explanation./44281

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that most of the answers giving mathematical explanation for this "*how does moving tortoise to beginning of linked list while keeping the hare at meeting place, followed by moving both one step at a time make them meet at starting point of cycle?*"

The following method also does the same like floyd cycle detection behind the scenes but the rationale is simple but at a cost of O(n) memory.

I would like to add an easier approach/rationale to find the beginning of the cycle. Since this method was not mentioned anywhere, I tested this here: [https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle-ii/](http://leetcode) and It passed all the testcases.

Let's consider that we've been given head reference of the LinkedList.

```
     public ListNode detectCycle(ListNode head) {
     
            // Consider a fast pointer which hops two nodes at once.
            // Consider a slow pointer which hops one node at once.
            // If the linked list contains a cycle,
            // these two pointers would meet at some point when they are looping around the list.
            // Caution: This point of intersection need not be the beginning of the cycle.
            ListNode fast = null;
            ListNode slow = null;
            if (head != null) {
                if (head.next != null) {
                    fast = head.next.next;
                    slow = head;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
                // Why do we need collection here? Explained below
                Set<ListNode> collection = new HashSet<>();
                if (fast == slow) {
                  // Once the cycle is detected, 
                     we are sure that there is beginning to the cycle.
                  // In order to find this beginning, 
                  // 1. move slow pointer to head and keep fast pointer at 
                        the meeting point.
                  // 2. now while moving slow and fast pointers through a 
                        single hop, store the slow reference in a collection.
                  // 3. Every time you hop the fast pointer, check the fast 
                        pointer reference exits in that collection.
                  // Rationale: After we moved slow pointer to the head, 
                     we know that slow pointer is coming behind the fast
                     pointer, since collection is storing all nodes from the 
                     start using slow pointer, there is only one case we get 
                     that fast pointer exists in the collection when slow 
                     pointer started storing the nodes which are part of the 
                     cycle. Because slow pointer can never go ahead of fast 
                     pointer since fast pointer already has an head-start, at 
                     the same time, the first occurence will always be of the 
                     starting point of the cycle because slow pointer can't 
                     go ahead of fast pointer to store other nodes in the 
                     cycle. So, the moment we first find fast pointer in that 
                     collection means, that is the starting point of the 
                     cycle.
                    slow = head;
                    collection.add(slow);
                    while (!collection.contains(fast)) {
                        slow = slow.next;
                        collection.add(slow);
                        fast = fast.next;
                    }
                    return fast;
                }
                fast = fast.next.next;
                slow = slow.next;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I know there is already an accepted answer for this problem but I'll still try to answer in a fluid manner.
Assume :

```
The length of the Path is 'X+B' where 'B' is the length of the looped path and X of the non looped path. 
    Speed of tortoise : v
    Speed of hare     : 2*v 
    Point where both meet is at a distance 'x + b - k' from the starting point.
```

Now, let the hare and the tortoise meet after time 't' from beginning.

Observations:

If, Distance traveled by the tortoise   = v*t   = x + (b-k) (say)

Then, Distance traveled by the hare     = 2*v*t = x + (b - k) + b (since the hare has traversed the looped part once already)

Now, there meeting times are same.

=> x + 2*b - k = 2* (x + b - k)

=> x = k

This of course means that the length of the path that is not looped is same as the distance of the starting point of the loop from the point where both meet.

Comment: You can't assume that the tortoise travelled exactly x+b-k by the time they meet. Also, I don't understand how you got x+2*b-k for the hare's distance.

Comment: Because the hare would have traversed the looped part once already to have to met the tortoise.. I didn't explain it there :/

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your pointers meet at the intersection of point y and z.

n and m are the numbers of loops faster and slower pointer takes respectively before meeting.

Refer to the image for the rest of the proof.
[Find the starting point of loop in linked list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDuC0.jpg)