# How to prove the first part of Floyd's algorithm for cycle detection?

Tags: algorithm

In the first part of Floyd's algorithm, the hare moves two steps for every step of the tortoise. If the tortoise and hare ever meet, there is a cycle, and the meeting point is part of the cycle, but not necessarily the first node in the cycle.

I cannot understand why two pointers must meet sometime if the circle exist? How about replace "two steps" with "three steps"?

I hope someone could prove it to me...

Comment: @MattTimmermans Actually no.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I don't think this is a duplicate. This question asks a proof of _why_ the 2 pointers are guaranteed to meet, while the other question asks the proof of the method to find the starting point of the cycle, once the 2 pointers have met.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130246/why-increase-pointer-by-two-while-finding-loop-in-linked-list-why-not-3-4-5/5130334#5130334

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that when both tortoise and hare are in the cycle, their **relative** speed becomes 1, virtually hare chases standing tortoise with this speed, so hare will meet tortoise in `N <= Cycle_Len` steps.

You can replace "two steps" with "three steps", but you have to check whether they meet at every hare substep

Comment: Oh! I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the second part of the question, it is not guaranteed to detect the cycles containing even number of nodes, if the hare moves at `3` steps and tortoise at `1` step. If the tortoise moved at `2` steps, however, the cycle detection would be possible.

**In general, if the hare moves at `H` steps, and tortoise moves at `T` steps, you are guaranteed to detect a cycle iff `H = T + 1`.**

Consider the hare moving relative to the tortoise.

- Hare's speed relative to the tortoise is `H - T` nodes per iteration.
- Given a cycle of length `N =(H - T) * k`, where `k` is any positive
  integer, the hare would skip every `H - T - 1` nodes (again, relative
  to the tortoise), and it would be impossible to for them to meet if
  the tortoise was in any of those nodes.
- The only possibility where a meeting is guaranteed is when `H - T - 1 = 0`.

Comment: That's not quite correct. When T=1, a meeting is guaranteed for any H > 1, as long as the tortoise and hare start on the same node. See my answer answer here for details: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913499/proof-of-floyd-cycle-chasing-tortoise-and-hare