# how to find whether linked list is a circular or non-circular list?

Tags: java

A linked list class is given. we have to find whether it is circular or not? I have already find the question on this website but did not find any relevant answer.

Comment: I don't believe this is question is Java specific. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482886/cycle-detection-with-the-hare-and-tortoise-approach or this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code for the list implementation, a quick test would be to see if the head pointer and last node pointers point to the same element.  This information is indirectly accessible through the class iterator.