# Finding the junction node in a linklist having a loop in it

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding loop in a singly linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275587/finding-loop-in-a-singly-linked-list)

Given is a link list which has a loop in it.

I want to find out where does the loop start (The node which is pointed by two nodes).

Please suggest solution for this with minimum complexity.

Comment: @KingsIndian.. I am trying to find the point where the loop starts...so i think that its not a duplicate

Comment: @KundanKumar: The linked question & accepted answer shows how to do it, after you discover you have a cycle.

Comment: Finding the junction point is a *different, but related* problem. I'd add a counter.

Comment: The posted link explicitly covers that as well.

Comment: Could you please elaborate little more?

Comment: I stand corrected. I did not scroll all the way to the bottom. BTW: IMHO the example in the link should have labeled the nodes with letters, instead of numbers.