# Why do we need to detect a loop in a linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, cyclic-reference

I see many Q/A on how to detect a loop in linked list, but I want to understand is why we want to do that, in other words what are the practical use cases of detecting a loop in a linked list

Comment: "linked list" and "loop" is a contradiction by definition. Are you sure the questions were not about loops in general graphs?

Comment: @Henry This is a fairly common interview questions. OP is probably asking for scenarios in practical work where this might be applicable.

Answer (score 4):

In real life, you'll probably never need to detect a loop in a linked list, BUT the algorithms for doing that are important and I have used them in real life many times.

Pretty often, for example, I will process a linked data structure recursively when it's supposed to be tree-shaped.  If it isn't tree-shaped and has a cycle, however, that would cause infinite recursion and a stack overflow, so I like to catch that before it explodes.  I usually use Brent's cycle-finding algorithm for that, because it's easy to fit into my recursive processing and has extremely low overhead.

Cycle finding algorithms are also useful in Pollard's "rho" factorization algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm)

The ideas you learn when learning about these algorithms will also be useful when learning other more complex things later on.

ETA:

I should add that common situations that produce cycles by mistake are those in which users specifically create the links.  For example in Java a class can have a superclass, and the programmer writes `class C extends A {}`, for example.  The `extends` keyword creates a link between classes.  If he also writes `class A extends C`, then he has created a cycle and the compiler has to detect that condition.

Comment: one more thing, may be this is very trivial for you , when we are creating a list then we always keep on adding new elements, then how does linked list form a loop. or is it by mistake the developer writes some faulty logic which creates loop

Comment: Also do we have to check for loops in a linked list before we start iterating.

Comment: You don't have to check for loops before starting iterating, since it is possible to combine cycle detection with the processing - with minimal overhead (just keep one more pointer and update it). If you don't process the entire list (e.g. you are looking for an element in a linked list and it occurs early in the list), it would be inefficient to first check for cycles. However, if you change the elements while processing you have to consider it in more detail.

Comment: @NikhilBansal When linked lists are made by adding elements, there is no significant likelihood that it will end up with a cycle.  That's one of the reasons why you'll probably never need to check for a cycles in a linked list :).   Trees are often made by creating nodes with references to other nodes, which is more dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

linked list with loop has no end , linked list contains two links to some node
Iterating through the  linked list will yield all nodes in the loop multiple times A malformed (with unknown loop) linked list with a loop causes iteration over the list to fail because the iteration will never reach the end of the list. Therefore, it is desirable to be able to detect that a linked list is have loop before trying an iteration

you can find answer here

https://blog.ostermiller.org/find-loop-singly-linked-list

Answer (score 0):

Because, if you have a list like this (for example):

```
head -> A -> B -> C -+
             ^       |
             +-------+
```

and the code to traverse it as follows:

```
node = head
while node <> null:
    processNode(node)
    node = node.next
```

then you will *never* complete the loop. It will happily process `A, B, C, B, C, B, C,...` for eternity (or until the heat death of the universe, whichever comes first).

A normal linked list will never *have* a cycle in it. In order to *detect* such a degenerate list, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275587/finding-loop-in-a-singly-linked-list/10275611#10275611).

Note that some cyclic linked lists are indeed valid. One example I've seen was a process list used for scheduling where the head and tail are irrelevant (since the thing that processes them *wanted* to loop over them forever). Hence the scheduler would be something like:

```
curr = somePointInList()
while true:
    runForABit(curr)
    curr = curr.next
```