# Does the Linked List have a cycle?

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I'm stuck on the following leetcode problem.

Given a singly linked list determine if there exists a cycle. If so, return True. Otherwise, return False.

My reasoning: Allow for two pointers to go through the entire single linked list. One of the pointers move one node at a time while the other pointer will touch every other node. If there exists a cycle the pointers will eventually meet.

Here is my attempt (in python):

```
# Edge Case
if head == None:
    return False
currA = head
currB = head

while currA and currB:
    currA = currA.next
    if currB.next:
        currB = currB.next.next
    if currA == None or currB == None:
        return False
    if currA == currB:
        return True
return False
```

I submitted this code to leetcode and I was able to pass all the test cases except the really long one.

However, the following code works fine (written by someone else):

```
if not head or not head.next: return False        
slow, fast = head, head.next
while slow != fast:
    if not fast or not fast.next: return False
    slow, fast = slow.next, fast.next.next
return True
```

To me, the main difference is the while statement's condition. However, I still don't see the error in my code.

Comment: So your solution is too slow or what?

Comment: Comparisons with None should be done using `is None`, not `== None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two other differences between these two solutions. The first one is trivial; your solution initialises `currB = head`, whereas the other solution's `fast` variable is initialised as `head.next`. This should have almost no impact on the working of the algorithm.

The difference that matters is that your solution leaves `currB` unchanged when `currB.next` is `None`. The other solution *terminates* in that case by returning `False`, but yours will sit there with `currB` at the last node, unchanged, while `currA` steps along towards the end of the list. Eventually, `currA` reaches the last node, and at that point `currA` and `currB` are equal; so your algorithm thinks it has detected a cycle, but really it's because your `currB` pointer stopped moving forwards and the other one caught up with it.

This problem doesn't occur for every non-cyclic list; only when `currB` ends up as the last node. This depends on the parity of the length of the list, since `currB` advances two steps each time, it may go to the second-last node instead of the last one, in which case the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Ironically, this algorithm is sometimes called the "hare and tortoise" algorithm because of how one pointer traverses the list faster than the other; and just like Aesop's story, your hare goes to sleep and the tortoise catches it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to examine your code (i.e., run it in your head) for the case of:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -|
```

That's the simplest case where your algorithm breaks.

Your code will set both `a` and `b` to point to `1` then enter the loop. `a` then advances to `2` and `b` advances to `3`.

In the next loop iteration, `a` advances to `3` but `b` stays at `3` because `b.next` is null. This means that `a` is free to advance without `b` either advancing faster or finding the end. Eventually, `a` will catch up to `b`<sup>(a)</sup> and you will consider that a looped list.

What you *need* to do instead is is advance `b` by two if possible but, if not, advance it as far as you can.

This is as simple as (pseudo-code):

```
b = b.next
if b is not null:
    b = b.next
```

That way, `b` is guaranteed to either keep ahead of `a` or find the list end.

---

If you're interested in more in-depth knowledge on this algorithm, have a look at [Finding loop in a singly linked-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275587/finding-loop-in-a-singly-linked-list/10275611#10275611), which explains both the algorithm itself in detail, *and* provides a way to find the start of the loop.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Interestingly, this is exactly what happens in the actual tortoise and hare fable. The hare stops to take a rest and the tortoise plods along, eventually passing the hare and winning the race.

Well, it *would* win the race if we didn't call a stop as soon as it caught up :-)