# Algorithm to determine whether loop exists in a linked list

Tags: algorithm, loops, linked-list

So I recently encountered the algorithm to determine whether a cycle exists in a linked list. The codes are as follows:

```
public boolean hasCycle(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null) {
        return false;
    }
    ListNode fast = head;
    ListNode slow = head;
    while (fast != null) {
        if (fast.next == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (fast.next == slow) {
            return true;
        }
        fast = fast.next.next;
        slow = slow.next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When trying to prove the correctness of this algorithm, I come up with an idea:
Suppose the perimeter of the cycle is "a", the time elapsed before two pointers meet is "t". Since the speed of the "fast" node moves twice as fast as the "slow" node, we can get the mathematical relation:

2t mod a = t mod a

Now "a" is a constant represents perimeter, and "t" could be 1,2,3.... Then, how do I prove that no matter what value "a" is, we can always find a "t" such that the above equation is solvable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2936213/1835769

Comment: does the equation correct if the cycle does not start at the first node?  eg: 1->2, 2->3, 3->4, 4->5, 5->3,  cycle = {3,4,5,3}

Comment: Any `t = 0 mod a` solves `2t = t mod a`.  You also need `t >= s`, where   it takes `s` steps to enter the cycle.

Comment: @MattTimmermans ummm...I think maybe it is the same after I think for a while:  2t -s =  t-s (a)   so 2t = t (a),   not sure though

Comment: @shole, you need both conditions.  If it takes 13 steps to enter a cycle of length 10, then the pointers will meet at t=20 and t=30, but not t=10

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yup you are right

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track! Hint: what happens to your formula after *a* iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both pointer starts at same point within the cycle (and this does not count as meeting)

`2t =  t (a)`

=> `2t - t = 0 (a)`

=> `t = 0 (a)`

which means at t = a*k, both pointers will meet at starting point after elapsed  time is multiples of the cycle length.

It is true for all `a >= 2`, because when time equals to `k*a` for all `k>1`, the slow pointer exactly runs k cycles long, while the fast pointer runs twice faster, so it runs 2k cycles long, still they meet at the same point which is the starting point.

Comment: I got lost at your second step : ( how do you get 2t - t = 0 (a) from 2t =  t (a)?

Comment: Just minus t%a both side?