# Linked Lists: Detect a Cycle

Tags: data-structures

> Hello.. I was trying to solve this question from hackerrank. I am getting False for all the Input condition. Can't figure out where I am going wrong. The objective is detect loops in a linkedlist. Here is the link to the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-linked-list-cycle
>   Please help.
>
> ```
>     My solution is :
>
>     /*
>     Detect a cycle in a linked list. Note that the head pointer may be 'null' if the list is empty.
>
>     A Node is defined as: 
>         class Node {
>             int data;
>             Node next;
>         }
>     */
>
>     boolean hasCycle(Node head) {
>
>         int counter = 0;
>
>        if(head == null || head.next == null)  
> //if the list is empty or if there is only one node in the list
>            {
>            return false;
>        }else
>            {
>            Node slow = head;  //initialize both the pointers to head
>            Node fast = head;
>
>            while( (slow != fast)  )    //loop if slow and fast are not equal 
>                {
>
>                slow = slow.next;   //slow shifts by 1
>                fast = fast.next.next;  //fast shifts by 2
>
>                if( (fast == null ) )   //when fast reaches null, there is no cycle
>                    {
>                    counter = 0;  //false, no cycle
>                       break;
>
>                } //end of inner if stmt
>                else if(slow == fast)  
> //when both the the pointers meet, there is a cycle
>                    {
>                    counter = 1;   //true, there is cycle
>                    break;
>                } //end of inner else stmt
>
>            } //end of while loop
>
>        } //end of else stmt
>            if(counter == 0)
>                {
>                return false;
>            }
>            return true;
>
>     }  //end of method
> ```

Comment: Please tag a language

Comment: You initialize `slow` and `fast` to `head` so`while( (slow != fast)  )` will be `false` and the loop never entered.

Comment: May be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32190575/1835769

Comment: oh ya.. I added a do while loop and it passed all test conditions. thanks for your time.:)