# Find start of loop of a link list - Floyds cycle detection algorithm

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to write code to detect the start of a loop using Floyds cycle detection algorithm.
My link list is like this

```
1->2->3->4->5->6
         |_____|
```

This is the code I am using

```
bool findCycle(Node* root)
{
    auto slow = root;
    auto fast = slow->next->next;
    while (slow != nullptr && fast != nullptr)
    {
        if (slow == fast)
        {
            //Yes there is a loop. Lets find the start of the loop
            //Move slow to the head again and move by one pointer each.
            slow = root;
            while (slow != nullptr && fast != nullptr)
            {
                if (slow != fast)
                {
                    slow = slow->next;
                    fast = fast->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "The loop starts at node " << slow->val;
                    return true;
                }
                
            }
          
            
        }
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have managed to detect the loop at 5. At that point I move the slow pointer to the head and keep the faster pointer at 5. Now I move each pointer by 1 and I expect them to cross at a specific node but they never cross. Is my algorithm wrong ? What am I doing wrong.

Comment: If both pointers are moving at the same speed but start at different points, how would you ever expect them to cross?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936213/explain-how-finding-cycle-start-node-in-cycle-linked-list-work

Comment: Check out the most upvoted answer. I am trying to figure this out using Floyds

Comment: So your outer loop sequence is 1,3 2,5 3,4 4,6 5,5 at which point you've detected a loop.  Your inner loop goes 1,5 2,6 3,4 4,5 at which point your `while` loop will be infinite because the pointers will never meet up.  The link you gave is interesting but I'm not sure I can trust the answers since you seem to have a compelling counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is "Floyd's algorithm", but you can do some counting of the loop size to help out.

The moment you detect there is a loop with your loop detection algorithm, count how many elements there are in the loop:

```
// upon discovering that you are "in the loop"
Node* loop = current;
int count = 1;
current = current->next;
while (current != loop) {
    count++;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Now that you know the `count` of elements in the loop, set up another traversal from the start as follows

```
previous = root;
current = root;
lookahead = root;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    lookahead = lookahead->next;
}
```

Then traverse in `count` sized jumps until you redetect the cycle:

```
while (current != lookahead) {
    previous = current;
    current = lookahead;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        lookahead = lookahead->next;
    }
}
```

When the loop exits, `previous` will be within `count` elements outside the start of the loop.  So then we can traverse with one pointer going "one by one" and the other incrementing in `count` elements.

```
    current = previous;
    lookahead = previous;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        lookahead = lookahead->next;
    }

    while(current != lookahead) {
        current = current->next;
        current = current->next;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            lookahead = lookahead->next;
        }
    }
```

When the above loop exits, `current` points to the start of the loop.  I think there is a way to optimize that last loop

Answer (score -1):

The first part of the algorithm given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd%27s_tortoise_and_hare) is:

> ```
> def floyd(f, x0):
>     # Main phase of algorithm: finding a repetition x_i = x_2i.
>     # The hare moves twice as quickly as the tortoise and
>     # the distance between them increases by 1 at each step.
>     # Eventually they will both be inside the cycle and then,
>     # at some point, the distance between them will be
>     # divisible by the period λ.
>     tortoise = f(x0) # f(x0) is the element/node next to x0.
>     hare = f(f(x0))
>     while tortoise != hare:
>         tortoise = f(tortoise)
>         hare = f(f(hare))
> ```

You forgot to advance `slow` once as the first step.

The line

```
    auto slow = root;
```

should be:

```
    auto slow = root->next;
```

Comment: do u mean when i find the loop and move slow point to the head I need to move it one step again ?

Comment: @JamesFranco No. The "move the slow pointer to head" part in Wikipedia is `tortoise = x0`. No extra step is needed here.