# Why in Floyd's Algorithm for cycle detection if we take fast as head.next than the solution becomes wrong?

Tags: c++, linked-list, floyd-cycle-finding

So I was solving leetcode's question where we have to return the node where the tail connects, but the solution came wrong when I took `fast = head->next` and came right when I took `fast = head`. I understood how the latter was correct but I didn't quite understood why?

**Example:**
Input: head = [3,2,0,-4], pos = 1
Output: tail connects to node index 1

**wrong code**

```
ListNode *slow = head, *fast = head->next;
    
    while(fast && fast->next) {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
        
        if(slow == fast)
            break;
    }
    if(fast == NULL || fast->next == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    slow = head;
    while(fast != slow){
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
    }
    return fast;
```

**correct code**

```
ListNode *slow = head, *fast = head;
    
    while(fast && fast->next) {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next->next;
        
        if(slow == fast)
            break;
    }
    if(fast == NULL || fast->next == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    slow = head;
    while(fast != slow){
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
    }
    return fast;
```

Comment: You might find a hint at [Explain how finding cycle start node in cycle linked list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2936213/5987).  I'm sure it has something to do with the math that gives you the starting point of the cycle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explain how finding cycle start node in cycle linked list work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936213/explain-how-finding-cycle-start-node-in-cycle-linked-list-work)